# JavaFX - Absolute layout, where a component can extend over another without moving it

Tags: javafx, hover, components, position

I have one component with two state "viewed" and "edited". When "edited", the component must display some controls and take more horizontal space. In one view I have many of those component displayed vertically. And I would like to have the "edited" component hover his siblings so that the view is not resized vertically.

```
              All "viewed"                     One "edited"
              +--------------------+           +--------------------+
              | +----------------+ |           | +----------------+ |
              | | Lorem ipsum    | |           | | Lorem ipsum    | |
              | | dolor.         | |           | | dolor.         | |
              | +----------------+ |           | +----------------+ |
              | +----------------+ |           |+------------------+|
              | | Will be edited | |           ||  I am edited     ||
              | +----------------+ |           ||..................||
              | +----------------+ |           ||  [Cancel] [Save] ||
              | | Will be        | |           |+------------------+|
              | |partially hidden| |           | |partially hidden| |  
              | +----------------+ |           | +----------------+ |
              +--------------------+           +--------------------+
```

Being new with JavaFx I have to admit that I have no idea n how to do that. I have read that the "absolute" `Pane` or `AnchorPane` may be helpful to display one component hover another. It also seems that `StackPane` can be used to hide or display the components when edited.

Are you aware of something that can be used for that effect or could you give me some hints on how to build it ?

Tanks a lot

Comment: Put the "viewed" and "edited' views in a stack pane, and call `setVisible()` to toggle which you see. Their sizes will be accounted for even if their `visible` property is false.

Comment: Okay, that will do the trick to hide/dislay the controls. But what about *not* resizing the container. I do not want to move the component below when the "edited" one will grow.

Comment: Oh, OK, I think I misunderstood what you are trying to do. You're probably not going to get much useful help unless you post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example how it is possible with the use of `StackPane`:

**Controller class:**

```
package example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField leftTF, rightTF;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        TextField[] tfs = new TextField[]{leftTF, rightTF};

        for (TextField tf : tfs) {

            // Create and show buttons under the text field on text changed:
            tf.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                VBox vBox = (VBox) tf.getParent();
                if (vBox.getChildren().size() == 1) {
                    Button cancelBtn = new Button("Cancel");
                    Button saveBtn = new Button("Save");
                    HBox hBox = new HBox(cancelBtn, saveBtn);
                    hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-padding: 3;");
                    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    vBox.getChildren().add(hBox);

                    // Lower left and right padding to have more space horizontally:
                    vBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 3, 10, 3));
                    vBox.toFront();

                    // Remove overlaying box on button click and change padding to original values:
                    Button[] btns = new Button[]{cancelBtn, saveBtn};
                    for (Button btn : btns) {
                        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
                            vBox.getChildren().remove(1);
                            vBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 10, 10, 10));
                            tf.requestFocus();
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<HBox spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="example.Controller">
   <children>
      <GridPane hgap="10.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgrey;">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="150.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <HBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </HBox.margin>
         <children>
            <AnchorPane>
               <children>
                  <Label style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;" text="Lorem ipsum dolor." wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </Label>
               </children>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </AnchorPane>
            <StackPane GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </GridPane.margin>
               <children>
                  <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="leftTF" text="not being edited">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                     <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </StackPane.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </VBox>
                  <AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: tomato;">
                     <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="40.0" />
                     </StackPane.margin>
                     <children>
                        <VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label text="Will be" />
                              <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" text="partially hidden" />
                           </children>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </VBox>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <GridPane hgap="10.0" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgrey;">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="150.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <AnchorPane>
               <children>
                  <Label style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;" text="Lorem ipsum dolor." wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </Label>
               </children>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </AnchorPane>
            <StackPane GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </GridPane.margin>
               <children>
                  <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="rightTF" text="being edited">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                     <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </StackPane.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </VBox>
                  <AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: tomato;">
                     <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="40.0" />
                     </StackPane.margin>
                     <children>
                        <VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label text="Will be" />
                              <Label text="partially hidden" />
                           </children>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </VBox>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: That seems to do the trick. However the last node "Will be partially hidden" is inside nested in the same panel as "not being edited". All those lines ("Lorem ipsum dolor.", "not being edited" and "will be partially hidden") should be added/removed and I would like to avoid nesting them, managing one list is easier than a tree.